# Solving equations with complex numbers and rational power

Tags: complex-numbers

How to solve equation $x^{\frac{3}{2}}=i$?
De Moivre's formula fails.
Wolframalpha gives $x=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}$.

Is there any other solutions? Is there infinitely many solutions?

Comment: What does $x^{2/3}$ mean to you for complex $x$? Once you have an answer to that, you will be quite a bit closer to an answer to your problem.

Comment: What are the possibilities? What assumptions should I made if I'm only given this equation?

Comment: "All numbers which when raised to the second power becomes a cube root of $x$" is one. And $e^{2/3\cdot \ln x}$ is another (with the complex logarithm, which is multivalued). I'm sure there are more. If you are given this in a book or something, they really ought to have explained this first.

Comment: How both these attempts are handled?

Comment: "De Moivre's formula fails."  Why on earth do you say that???

Comment: Maybe not the best way to answer but $x^{\frac 32} = i\implies x^3 = i^2 =-1= e^{\pi i}=\cos \pi + i \sin \pi$ so ......

Answer (score 0):

$x^{\frac 32} = k$ means that i) $x^3 = k^2$ and that $-\frac \pi 2 < \arg k \le \frac \pi 2$.

So $x^3 = i^2 = -1$ and so by De Moivre $x= \frac {1 +\sqrt 3}2, \frac {1-\sqrt 3}2,-1$.  Of these three, the only one with an argument between $-\frac \pi 2$ and $\frac \pi 2$ is $x= \frac {1 +\sqrt 3}2$

==== old incorrect answer ====

What do you mean De Moivres formula fails?

$i = e^{i(\frac \pi2 + 2k\pi)}=\cos \frac \pi 2 + i \sin \frac \pi 2$. so $x^{\frac 32} = i$ is solved by $e^{i(\frac 23(\frac \pi 2 + 2k \pi))}=\cos (\frac 23(\frac \pi 2 + 2k \pi)) + i \sin (\frac 23(\frac \pi 2 + 2k \pi))$

Note if $k=0$ then $x= \cos \frac \pi 3 + i\sin \frac \pi 3 = \frac 12 + i\frac {\sqrt 3}2$ which is wolfram's answer.

==== to make the old answer correct we must add....====

However $x$ must be a *principal* square root so we must have $-\frac \pi 2 < \frac 23(\frac \pi 2 + 2k \pi) \le \frac \pi 2$.

Comment: If $k=0$, then $x=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)+i \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$ and it is correct solution. However, if $k=1$ then $x=\cos\left(\frac{5\pi}{3}\right)+i \sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{3}\right)$ and this solution is incorrect.

Comment: You're right that I mean $k=0$.  But if $k = 1$ then $x=\cos\left(\frac{5\pi}{3}\right)+i \sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{3}\right) = \frac 12 -i\frac {\sqrt 3}2$ which is *perfectly* correct.  As is $k = 2$ and $x = -1$ as $(-1)^{\frac 32} = \pm i$..

Comment: If $x=\cos\left(\frac{5\pi}{3}\right)+i \sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{3}\right)$ the $x^{\frac 32}=\cos\frac {5\pi}2 + i \sin\frac {5\pi}2 = \cos\frac \pi 2 + i \sin \frac pi 2 = 0 + i*1 = i$.  So that's a *correct* solution. Why did you say it was incorrect.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F2-sqrt%283%29%2F2*i%29%5E%283%2F2%29

Comment: @AndrewFount Hmmm, guess you are right.  $a^{\frac km}=v$ can not have $m$ values so we must *arbitrarily* define a *principal* $m$th root of $a$.  thatn is the one where $-\frac \pi m < \arg v \le \frac \pi m$.